# Validating objects integer property with hibernate validator

Tags: hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to validate attribute abc using hibernate validator to check if its null or not.

```
class A {
@NotNull
private B meta;
}

class B {
@NotNull(message = "missing field")
private int abc;
}
```

When I try to insert data of my pojo class A without having abc field in it, it still accepts it without validating it. How can I get "missing field" error since I'm not passing abc attribute at all?

If I don't pass abc attribute at all, I want error: "missing field", how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. Use Integer object and things starts working & also have @Valid tag in class A.